# Prove that any amount of money of at least 14c can be made up using 3c and 8c coins

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I am reading a book on Discrete Mathematics, and I am on the chapter of mathematical induction.

The first problem is the fairly common example of 1+2+...+n = n(n+1)/2, which I didn't have trouble with, but now this question came up and I don't know how to prove it using induction.

> Use mathematical induction to show that any amount of money of at least 14c can  be made up using 3c and 8c coins

I imagine the first part is to break it into cases... but I am a bit stuck. That doesn't seem like induction. Could anyone point in the right direction for a problem like this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Show it's true for $14, 15, 16$ and subtract $3$ in the induction step.

Comment: @Integrator :D I should be careful about downvoting then.

Comment: I noticed the book did a similar proof... _for all integers n>=8, nc can be obtained using 3c and 5c coins_. They seemed to state the two cases are there are and aren't 5c coins among them. In the case there are, 5c can be replaced with 2 3c coins, satisfying k+1, and if there isn't, since it is at least 8, the minimum is 3c, so 3 3c coins can be replaced with 2 5c coins also satisfying k+1. Not sure if this makes sense though...